# Summing based on different currencies

Tags: mysql

I am looking to sum the total price in `GBP` `SUM(price)` but I need to convert USD to GBP by multiplying by `0.74`

```
+---------+-------+
| country | price |
+---------+-------+
| GBP     |     1 |
| USD     |     2 |
| GBP     |     3 |
| USD     |     4 |
+---------+-------+
```

I have tried this SQL:

```
SELECT
    IF(`country` = 'USD',
        SUM(price * 0.74), 
        SUM(price)
    ) AS price
FROM `products`
```

But it is returning the error:

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a sum of prices over the entire table, and scale the USD prices to GBP by multiplying `0.74`, otherwise use the original value for GBP:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'USD' THEN 0.74 * price ELSE price END) AS price
FROM products;
```

[image]

### Demo

A nicer way to handle forex rates would be to have a separate table which converts any currency into USD and back again.  Then, you could simply do a join to get the result you wanted, rather than having to hard code a forex rate into the query.

Comment: apart from it should be `country='USD'`